Debugging a Multicore Kernel Initialization on Raspberry Pi 3B
I am developing a simple kernel for Raspberry Pi 3B intended to run basic tasks on all four cores. However, it appears that only the primary core is running kernel_init, and the other cores never start. Here's the relevant part of my code:
.globl _start
_start:
    mrs    x0, mpidr_el1
    and    x0, x0,#0xFF        // Check processor id
    cbz    x0, el1_entry        // Hang for all non-primary CPU
    b    proc_hang

proc_hang: 
    wfe
    b      proc_hang

el1_entry:
    adr    x0, bss_begin
    adr    x1, bss_end
    sub    x1, x1, x0
    bl     memzero

    mov    sp, #LOW_MEMORY
     // Initialize and start secondary cores on Raspberry Pi 3
    ldr x1, =start_core_1    // Address to jump to for secondary cores
    ldr x2, =0xE0                // Mailbox register for Core 1
    str x1, [x2]

    ldr x1, =start_core_2    // Address to jump to for secondary cores
    ldr x2, =0xE8                // Mailbox register for Core 2
    str x1, [x2]
    
    ldr x1, =start_core_3    // Address to jump to for secondary cores
    ldr x2, =0xF0                // Mailbox register for Core 3
    str x1, [x2]
    sev                           // Send event to wake up all cores

    bl    kernel_init
    b     proc_hang        // should never come here

start_core_1:
    ldr    x1, =LOW_MEMORY
    ldr    x2, =PAGE_SIZE
    add    sp, x1, x2          // sp = LOW_MEMORY + PAGE_SIZE
    bl     kernel_init
    b      start_core_1

start_core_2:
    ldr    x1, =LOW_MEMORY
    ldr    x2, =PAGE_SIZE
    add    sp, x1, x2, lsl #1  // sp = LOW_MEMORY + 2*PAGE_SIZE
    bl     kernel_init
    b      start_core_2

start_core_3:
    ldr    x1, =LOW_MEMORY
    ldr    x2, =PAGE_SIZE
    mov    x3, #3
    mul    x2, x2, x3          // x2 = 3 * PAGE_SIZE
    add    sp, x1, x2          // sp = LOW_MEMORY + 3*PAGE_SIZE
    bl     kernel_init
    b      start_core_3

extern "C" void kernel_init(void)
{
    uart_init();
    init_printf(0, putc);
    printf("processor ID: %d\n", get_core_number());
    while (1)
    {
        uart_send(uart_recv());
    }
}

.global get_core_number
    get_core_number:
    mrs x0, MPIDR_EL1      // Read MPIDR_EL1 into x0
    and x0, x0, #0xff      // Check processor id
    ret                    // Return, with the result in x0

Despite writing to the correct mailbox registers to wake up the secondary cores, the UART output shows only "processor ID: 0", and it seems like the secondary core-specific code never starts running. Based on my understanding of multicore programming, the output should be something like this if all of the cores are running:
processor ID: 0
processor ID: 2
processor ID: 1
processor ID: 3 (in random order of course)
I have tried setting different stack pointers for each core, as seen in the initialization code for start_core_X, but still, only the primary core seems active.
What I have tried is just doing something like this:
_start:
    adr    x0, bss_begin
    adr    x1, bss_end
    sub    x1, x1, x0
    bl     memzero
    mov    sp, #LOW_MEMORY
    bl    kernel_init

With this setup, I expected all cores to execute kernel_init as there's no logic to differentiate between cores (like checking MPIDR_EL1 to filter out non-primary cores). However, it seems that only the primary core is executing kernel_init, based on the output I'm getting:
processor ID: 0
Any insights or suggestions on why this is happening or how to ensure all cores run the initialization code would be greatly appreciated!
I am also partially going by this OS tutorial from github so a lot of my files came from here
https://github.com/s-matyukevich/raspberry-pi-os/tree/master

Can you verify that cores 1-3 at least start up and make it into proc_hang?

One issue with your tiny test example, where all cores try to execute kernel_init, is that they are all using the same stack, so if they do start then I'd expect unpredictable results as they all step on top of each other.  Still, I would think you'd probably at least get some output from the others.  How is LOW_MEMORY defined, by the way?

I apologize for the late response but this is the file that defines all of those variables
`#define PAGE_SHIFT    12
#define TABLE_SHIFT     9
#define SECTION_SHIFT    (PAGE_SHIFT + TABLE_SHIFT)
#define PAGE_SIZE      (1 << PAGE_SHIFT)
#define SECTION_SIZE    (1 << SECTION_SHIFT)
#define LOW_MEMORY     ((2 * SECTION_SIZE))`
which comes out to be 0x800000 in hex

After a bit more tinkering, I was able to solve my issue a little bit, but I am only getting a race condition from cores 0 and 1, I have no idea what is happening with the other ones. All I did is change prog_hang from what I had above to first do wfe then (when woken) check the mpidr_el1 register for the cpu id and if it is either 1, 2, or 3, it would branch to its respective start_core function. Don't know why I needed to load the function pointers into their mailbox registers if Im already branching to their function in proc_hang, but it breaks if I get rid of that so I left it in.

The above code is correct however instead of using the ldr instructions in these lines
ldr x1, =start_core_1
ldr x1, =start_core_2
ldr x1, =start_core_3
I had to use the adr instruction like this
adr x1, start_core_1
adr x1, start_core_2
adr x1, start_core_3
I found this out by looking at this repository
https://github.com/rhythm16/rpi4-bare-metal/blob/main/src/boot.S
This change was necessary because the adr instruction is specifically designed to compute the address of a label within the current assembly section, directly encoding the offset within the instruction itself.
This is a more updated version of the code above that works with all four cores:
.globl _start
_start:
    mrs x0, mpidr_el1       
    and x0, x0,#0x3     // Check processor id
    cbz x0, el1_entry       // Hang for all non-primary CPU
    b   proc_hang

proc_hang: 
    wfe
    b proc_hang


el1_entry:
    adr    x0, bss_begin
    adr    x1, bss_end
    sub    x1, x1, x0
    bl     memzero
    mov   sp, #LOW_MEMORY
    bl    wake_up_cores
    bl    kernel_init
    b     proc_hang        // should never come here

secondary:
    mrs x0, mpidr_el1
    and x0, x0, #0xFF // get processor id
    mov x1, #SECTION_SIZE
    mul x1, x1, x0 // multiply section size by processor id to give each core a different stack
    add x1, x1, #LOW_MEMORY
    mov sp, x1
    bl kernel_init

wake_up_cores:
    mov x0, #0
    adr x0, secondary
    mov x1, #0xe0
    str x0, [x1]
    mov x1, #0xe8
    str x0, [x1]
    mov x1, #0xf0
    str x0, [x1]
    sev

